# Scrollview not working just in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm creating custom view in android (I want to do it dynamically with Java code). And I extended Relative Layout to that class. And when I use Scroll View for this Relative Layout, it doesn't work(not scrolling and just showing one of the buttons from Relative Layout).

But when I change the Relative Layout to Linear Layout and set the Linear Layout orientation to Vertical it works and I can scroll the layout.

this the Custom Layout class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomLayout extends RelativeLayout {

public static ArrayList<Button> btnList;
int btnHeight = pxFromDp(getContext(), 70);

public CustomLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    setLayoutParams(params);

    //setOrientation(VERTICAL);  ---> for LinearLayout

    btnList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addButton(String buttonText, int id) {
    Button btn = new Button(getContext());

    if(id > 0)
        btn.setY(btnList.get(id - 1).getBottom());
    else
        btn.setY(0);

    btn.setText(buttonText);
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    btnList.add(btn);
    addView(btnList.get(id), id,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, btnHeight));
}

//just convert dpi to pixel
public static int pxFromDp(final Context context, float dp) {
    return (int) (dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
}
```

and this is my usage of this class with Scroll View:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    CustomLayout csLayout = new CustomLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++) {
        csLayout.addButton("Button " + i, i);
    }

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    sv.addView(csLayout);

    setContentView(sv);
}
}
```

remember that this Custom View Works with extending Linear Layout.

What should I do to work for Relative Layout too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using views inside a RelativeLayout, you will have to specify some additional attributes, like

```
android:layout_below="id"
android:layout_above ="id"
android:layout_toRightOf="id"
android:layout_toLeftOf="id"
```

for view to be above,below right and left one other(Relatively).

As you said in case on a LinearLayout it is working fine, because you have given a vertical orientation to that linear layout, what it means is whenever you add any element to it, it would automatically be below the last item added. That is why you are able to see the desired functionality with LinearLayout.

Also, as suggested earlier by @Devendra Singh, you should make sure that there in only 1 direct child to that ScrollView.

What is happening in your RelativeLayout is, that all the buttons are drawn, but they are drawn on top of each other. That is why you see only a single one appearing on screen. If you want to debug, try setting text on the button you added, and give it a number according to the for loop. You will see that the button which is shown is the last one added.

I hope this helps... happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

Because `ScrollView` can host only one direct child layout. and you are attaching more than one. better add your `Relativelayout` to a `LinearLayout`
Better documentation [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Better add a `LinearLayout` and the buttons to the `Linearlayout` and than add the linearlayout to your `CustomLayout`.Like

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    sv.setFillViewport(true);
    CustomLayout customLayout = new CustomLayout(this);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Button" + i);
        linearLayout.addView(button);
    }
    customLayout.addView(linearLayout);
    sv.addView(customLayout);
    setContentView(sv);
```

But it is really better you use `xml` to get your layouts accurately.

Comment: is relative layout more than one child by itself?

Comment: but when i do this(add Relative Layout to Scroll View) in XML it works correctly.

Comment: no but as you are adding the relative layout 20 times. so the 20 child added. you can add twenty 20 buttons to the relative layout and than try.

Comment: as you can see in my code, i didn't add relative layout for 20 times. i added buttons for 20 times. If you think i added relative layout for 20 times, now what should i write in my code?